# I have Domain Driven Design Concerns on my VS project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, design-patterns, asp.net-core, domain-driven-design

I am dealing with some architectural design concerns that is needed to be sorted out. My current architecture can be seen below. Each box is a project in visual studio, and they together forms solution.

My Core application is coded in WestCore.AppCore Context, and I have another project group called CSBINS (which includes system web service integrations) CSBINS is an merchant product that is why I found it better to seperate it to another project and only depend it with most commonly used interfaces from WestCore.AppCore.

Right now WestCore.Api does not have any logic in it. All the application logic is handled inside AppCore and AppCore.Csbins

The Problem is I sometimes have need to use WestCore.AppCore.Csbins services inside WestCore.AppCore which causes cross referencing issue.

the best approach right now that I think is to add Endpoint Services into WestCore.Api and move cross platform logic to Endpoint Services.

However I would like to get suggestions and design concerns about going further on this since I am very sure that there would be many design choices.

I am also considering to move common AppCore Interfaces and Classes to WestCore.AppCore.Common so that I wont need to reference whole WestCore.AppCore project to WestCore.AppCore.Csbins.

[image: Application Architecture]

Comment: Likely your libraries that are encountering circular references are trying to do too much. For example, libraries that depend on Csbins, should only be working with Csbins. Other libraries can reference those libraries (rather than Csbins) if you need to combine a set of functionalities. In other words, build your app up from discrete units of functionality and you'll naturally end up with a clean dependency tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using services inside other services - this is probably a bad thing and needs refactoring.

Those CORE projects look like are application services projects, it might help calling them 'WestCore.ApplicationServices', Core implies it belongs at the domain level.

It sounds like you need to impliment an anti corruption layer to integrate with the 3rd party vendor rather than creating a whole new 'domain' context. This should be as straightforward as degining an interface in your domain layer (personally I use the *Gateway suffix to identifiy interfaces that interact with external systems)

Not knowing anything about your domain I would probably start with something that looks like this: (I've assumed the csbins is some sort of payment or accounting gateway)

[image: rough architecture sketch indicating csbins domain project may not be required]

Also, I would strongly recommend avoiding "Common" and "Shared" libraries at the domain level, you shouldn't need them. Your interfaces and classes are DOMAIN objects and belong in your DOMAIN library. The Application Services should be using domain models directly and having implementation of domain interfaces supplied via Dependency Injection. Hopefully your Domain Models are fleshed out enough that your application service classes are just orchestration wrappers.